# pass data between controller after $state.go?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Imagine I have a list of items which is in the store controller. Then the user clicked on one of the item, it uses another controller, how do I get the items in item controller?

```
.controller('store', function($scope,$http,$state) {

    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: $rootScope.hostname + '/api/products',
      }).then(function successCallback(response) {
        $scope.items = response.data.product;

      }, function errorCallback(response) {
        alert(response.data)
      });

      $scope.GoItem = function(data){
        //data
        $state.go('app.item');
      }
})

.controller('item', function($scope,$http) {
   //how to get the data here?
})
```

Comment: you can create a service and inject them to both of them to have common logic

Answer (score 1):

Edit: I mistook the question. Since you are trying to pass between controllers, you have a couple of options.

1. Use $rootScope. This scope is shared across your entire app.
2. Use a service. Store your http call inside as a function.

Answer (score 1):

Use $stateParams to do this.

```
app.controller('store', function($scope, $http, $state) {
  $scope.items = [{
     'id': "1234",
     'name': 'XYZ'
  }, {
      'id': "123456",
      'name': 'ABC'
  }]

  $scope.GoItem = function(data) {
     $state.go('app-item', {
       'item': JSON.stringify(data)
   });
 }
})

app.controller('item', function($scope, $http, $stateParams) {
   console.log(JSON.parse($stateParams.item))
   $scope.item = JSON.parse($stateParams.item)
     //how to get the data here?
})
```

Created working Plunker. Hope it solve your problem. https://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:8rFfZljYNl3z1A4LKSL2?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

You can send the params as the second parameter in `$state.go('app.item', {'item':'my item'});`. Then resolve the params in the state config and pass the resolved items to the controller.

```js
.controller('StoreCtrl', function($scope,$http,$state) {

    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: $rootScope.hostname + '/api/products',
      }).then(function successCallback(response) {
        $scope.items = response.data.product;

      }, function errorCallback(response) {
        alert(response.data)
      });

      $scope.GoItem = function(data){
        //data
        $state.go('app.item', {'itemData', myItem});
      }
})

.controller('ItemCtrl', function($scope, $http, itemData) {
   //how to get the data here?
})
```

In your state config:

```js
$stateProvider
.state('store', {
  url:'/store',
  templateUrl: 'store.html',
  controller: 'StoreCtrl'
})
.state('item', {
  url:'/item',
  templateUrl: 'item.html',
  controller: 'ItemCtrl',
  params: {
    myItem: ''
  },
  resolve: {
    name: function($stateParams) {
      return $stateParams.myItem;
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

One more option could be $state.go('app.item',{param1 : var1,param2: var2});
Hope its helpful and looking for.
https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/pass-data-with-state-go/2897/2

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass this data to anywhere on your application. use $rootScope.$broadcast

E.g :

```
.controller('StoreCtrl', function($scope,$http,$state,$rootScope) {

    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: $rootScope.hostname + '/api/products',
      }).then(function successCallback(response) {
        $scope.items = response.data.product;

      }, function errorCallback(response) {
        alert(response.data)
      });

      $scope.GoItem = function(data){
        //data
        $rootScope.$broadcast("passData", yourdata);
        $state.go('app.item');
      }
})
```

On your second controller:

```
    .controller('item', function($scope,$http) {
      $scope.$on("passData", function(dataRecieved) {
    console.log(dataRecieved);
     });
})
```

You can use $stateParams also. this is more like angular 2 approach(EventEmitter).

Comment: in case if scope of first controller is parent to second controller you can also do $scope.$broadcast("passData",data).conversely if you want to broadcast data from child controller to parent use  $scope.$emit("passData",data). Note this is not exactly you need now but this are the ways we can  do when we know relation between scopes.